# How do I visualize compact convex sets?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis

I have hard time to visualize compact convex set in infinite dimensional spaces.

From Riesz theorem, one deduces a normed vector space is locally compact iff it is finite dimensional.

So an infinite dimensional normed space can't be locally compact. There can't be compact neighborhood floating all around in this case.

I want to visualize the following consequence, though I knew how to prove them. Let $S\subset E$ be a non-empty convex compact subset of $E$ where I will assume $E$ is hausdorff normed vector space. Then there is an extreme point of $S$ where $x$ is extreme if for any $y,z\in S$ s.t. $x$ lies in open linear segment between $y$ and $z$, then $y=z$. It looks like $S$ has some corner.

$\textbf{Q1:}$ How should I see compact sets in an infinite dimensional vector space? From banach alaoglu theorem, the unit sphere is compact in the dual space of a banach space but I can't see it.

$\textbf{Q2:}$ How should I see extreme point of a convex compact subset $S$?

Comment: What do you mean by "see"? Do you mean how to imagine these spaces in your mind?

Comment: @kkc It is better to see than to believe. So I want to "see" it by all means. Finite dimensional case is too easy to see. I do not know how to even see Banach Alaoglu theorem though proof is not too hard.

Comment: "From banach alaoglu theorem, the unit sphere is compact in the dual space of a banach space" this contains _two_ errors! The  theorem says the closed unit **ball** in the dual  is  **weak**-* compact.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich For any banach space $E$, you take embedding $(E^\star)_1\to\prod_{x\in E_1}[-1,1]$'s image via evaluation map is compact where $E_1$ is the unit sphere$(\leq 1)$ of corresponding space. That is what I mean. It is not clear whether weak topology always coincides with norm topology though but weak is certainly contained within norm.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich This topology is compatible with induced topology from $\prod_{x\in E}R$ via embedding $\prod_{x\in E_1}[-1,1]\to\prod_{x\in E_1}R\to\prod_{x\in E}R$ where the last map is obviously given by scaling components.

Comment: First, $\{x:||x||\le1\}$ is a _ball_, not a sphere. And second, the topology you're  talking about is the _weak_-* topology, not the weak topology or the norm topology. In this context if you say the ball is "compact" that means compact in the norm topology. (And it's  abundantly clear that the two topologies are different! If they were the same that would for example contradict the result you cited about an infinite-dimensional space not being locally compact.)